# How to write an if statement for "a list does not contain a string"?

Tags: c#, list, contains

The following IF statement checks if the ListexceptionCM contains the selected value of the dropdown list.

```
List<string> ExceptionCM = new List<string>;
if(exceptionsCM.Any(s => ddl_model.SelectedValue.Contains(s)) )
{
       //do something
}

List<string> ExceptionPM;
List<string> ExceptionDL;
List<string> ExceptionCL;
```

I would like to change the statement, so I can check if the the 4 list doesn't contains the selected value of dropdown. Could you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `All` to ensure all items in 4 lists do not contain:

```
var exceptions = new List<List<string>>()
{
    ExceptionCM, 
    ExceptionPM, 
    ExceptionDL, 
    ExceptionCL
}

if (exceptions.SelectMany(ex => ex)
              .All(s => !ddl_model.SelectedValue.Contains(s)))
{
}
```

**Edit:** `Any` is not correct in this case because it determines whether any elements of a collection satisfy a condition.

Comment: maybe a "!" before ddl_model.SelectedValue.Contains(s) ?

Comment: @NK: I edited my answer by using All instead of Any(), Any() is not correct in this case

Answer (score 2):

You can do like:

```
//combine all lists into a single IEnumerable<string>
IEnumerable<string> unionList = ExceptionCM.Union(ExceptionPM)
                                              .Union(ExceptionDL)
                                                  .Union(ExceptionCL);

//check against union list
if(unionList .Any(s => !ddl_model.SelectedValue.Contains(s)) )
{
   //do something
}
```

Something like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> ExceptionCM = new List<string>;
foreach(List<yourType> list in YourLists<List<YourType>>)
{
    if(exceptionsCM.Any(s => !list.Contains(s)) )
    {
       //do something
    }
{
List<string> ExceptionPM;
List<string> ExceptionDL;
List<string> ExceptionCL;
```

Just add the ! (not) operator before your **ddl_model.SelectedValue.Contains(s)** that returns a bool.

Comment: and to check if doesn't contains the other 3 lists, I can use && between ?

Comment: Thank you. But I have to check if the other 3 list doesn't contains the selected value. How I do that in the most efficient way ? Can I use : if(exceptionsCM.Any(s => !ddl_model.SelectedValue.Contains(s)) &&  if(exceptionsPM.Any(s => !ddl_model.SelectedValue.Contains(s)) && ... ?

Comment: you do a foreach iteration maybe?

Comment: yes you can use && operator for that. the same way which you hav shown above.